# reset static field to their initial value using reflexion in java

Tags: java, reflection

I use in my project a lib with some class with a lot of static field and other stuffs, who are indirectly updated and consulted at runtime in my app.
I can't update or ignore or mock this class.

How can I re-execute the method who initialise the static field of a class?

I'm currently writing test in my app, which trigger this class.
I want the static field of this class to be at their init state each time I start my app.

The issue is, setting manualy those static field is not possible, it would be too complexe. I need them to be put at their initial state "automaticaly"

I can't change anything to the code of the class, because it's in a lib.

Any idea how I can do that? With reflexion, maybe?

Comment: How about restarting the process?

Comment: It wont work, the different tests run on the same process

Answer (score -1):

If resetting static fields manually are too complex and classes are stateless, one of the way could be to use custom class loader and reload your classes whenever required.

[This article](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html) may provide some idea about loading and reloading classes.

You should watch out for performance hit.

Comment: This answer could be improved by including an example, perhaps sourced and attributed from the article which you've linked, which demonstrates how your proposed method might solve the problem presented in the question.